# Default value for top, bottom, right, left position properties

Tags: html, css

The default values of the top, bottom, left, right values of the position properties is auto, how is auto calculated by the user agent, what are those values?

Comment: "of the position properties"... Huh? The `position` property has values of "absolute", "relative", etc..

Comment: please read the question again,you're not understanding it.

Comment: *For non-replaced elements, the effect of this value depends on which of related properties have the value 'auto' as well. See the sections on the width and height of absolutely positioned, non-replaced elements for details. For replaced elements, the effect of this value depends only on the intrinsic dimensions of the replaced content. See the sections on the width and height of absolutely positioned, replaced elements for details.* — https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#position-props

Comment: Thanks Quentin, I will take a look at this.

Comment: Or, perhaps, it's not clear...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take `top` for example, from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/top

> For absolutely positioned elements (those with position: absolute or position: fixed), it specifies the distance between the top margin edge of the element and the top edge of its containing block.

So, `top: auto` for an absolutely positioned element means whatever the position of the element currently is, and can be effected by the `bottom` property.

> For relatively positioned elements (those with position: relative), it
>   specifies the amount the element is moved below its normal position.

So, `top: auto` for a relative positioned element it means the offset from it's original position, also based on the bottom property. If both are set to auto, then it won't offset anything

This would be the same for bottom, but opposite, and then similarly for the left/right relationship.

From http://vanseodesign.com/css/auto-positioning/

> The default value for the top, right, bottom and left properties is
>   auto, which means the absolutely positioned box will appear exactly
>   where it would have had if it wasn’t positioned. Since it’s removed
>   from the flow it will overlap any elements in the normal flow that
>   follow it, though.

Also of note is this:

> When both top and bottom are specified, as long as height is
>   unspecified, auto or 100%, both top and bottom distances will be
>   respected. Otherwise, if height is constrained in any way, the top
>   property takes precedence and the bottom property is ignored.